# How to copy between registers with a bitshift in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I can't figure out the right syntax to bitshift and ldr at the same time...here's what I've been trying,

```
ldr r4, r1, lsr #1
```

I want to divide r1 by two and store it in r4 in one swift motion.  However gcc is saying garbage following instruction.

Comment: ARM is a load/store architecture with a single ld/st unit. You can't pair any other operation with load/store except auto inc/dec of the address. VLIW computers (e.g. Movidius) have multiple load/store units and can pack a bunch of operations into a single instruction. ARM's barrel shifter is part of the ALU, so can be used during math/logical ops.

Comment: so the punchline there is use mov not ldr.  ldr is for reading from the data bus into a register, str for storing from a register to an address. mov, add, xor, etc are for moving from register to register with or without modification of the value

Comment: it is all in the arm docs, just have to look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mov` is the appropriate instruction to use for moving one register into another, not `ldr`.

The syntax in ARM mode would be:

```
mov r4, r1, lsr#1
```

In Thumb mode you could do (also works in ARM mode if you're using the [unified syntax](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/BABJIHGJ.html)):

```
lsr r4, r1, #1
```